# Into what non-navigable Pacific Ocean area did structural elements of the Progress MS16 cargo ship & Pirs module fall? Are there maps of these areas?

Tags: reentry, mission-design, safety, roscosmos, pirs

[This recent Roscosmos tweet](https://twitter.com/roscosmos/status/1419672251922792455) (found in CNET's [See astronaut's wild view of a discarded ISS module burning up](https://www.cnet.com/news/see-an-astronauts-wild-view-of-a-discarded-iss-module-burning-up-in-earths-atmosphere/)) says:

> The non-combustible structural elements of the #ProgressMS16 cargo ship and the #Pirs module fell in a **non-navigable area of the Pacific Ocean**.
>
> Thank you for your work, Progress and Pirs!

**Question:** Into what non-navigable Pacific Ocean area did structural elements of the Progress MS16 cargo ship & Pirs module fall? Are there maps of these areas?

I'm curious if there are officially designated "non-navigable" areas in the Pacific and other oceans, and if mission designers know about them and aim for them, and if so, into which one of them this mission aimed.

---

Image from the linked tweet; click for full size

[image: reentry of Progress MS16 cargo ship & Pirs module from Roscosmos tweet https://twitter.com/roscosmos/status/1419672251922792455]

Image from Exp. 65/66's Thomas Pesquet's [tweet](https://twitter.com/Thom_astro/status/1420029229517922304):

> So long DC1! After almost twenty years of service, instead of getting a medal First place medal, one of the  @Space_Station's oldest  @roscosmos modules got a little trip through the atmosphere. Shooting star #MissionAlpha https://flic.kr/p/2mdysX9

[image: from Exp. 65/66's Thomas Pesquet's tweet https://twitter.com/Thom_astro/status/1420029229517922304]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual **[spacecraft cemetery](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spacecraft_cemetery&oldid=1035225133),** known more formally as the **South Pacific Ocean Uninhabited Area.**

Wikipedia puts the general location at 43°34′48″S 142°43′12″W, and Roscosmos stated:

> At 14:42 UTC, [MS-16/Pirs] entered the dense layers of the Earth's atmosphere, in 10 more minutes, the incombustible elements dropped into the spacecraft cemetery in the non-navigable part of the Pacific Ocean, 3.6 thousand km from the city of Wellington and 5.8 thousand km from the city of Santiago.
>
> — Progress MS-16/Pirs spacecraft flight completed. July 26, 2021, 14:53 GMT. http://en.roscosmos.ru/22245/.

Plotting those ranges on [gcmap.com](http://www.gcmap.com/) with a red dot for the general location:

[image]

And it's a good match.

The *non-navigable area* is a reference to the *pole of inaccessibility* – neither term is literal. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pole_of_inaccessibility&oldid=1033951156#Oceanic_pole_of_inaccessibility) defines the latter as "the place in the ocean that is farthest from land" (shown by the blue dot/range).

The same on a globe:

[image]

<sub>They ought to name it *Earth's bullseye.*</sub>

Comment: Farthest from *inhabited* land.  It looks like it is somewhat close to Antarctica.

Comment: @DrSheldon: 2D projection does that. I now added the location of the actual pole of inaccessibility with range.